# Postgres SQL read binary value from string field?

Tags: postgresql

I have a column in a Postgres database that is of type varchar but has a binary value stored in it.
How can I return the binary value of the column in a way I can read it?

For example, at the moment I see "r" in the column, I want to see the 1's and 0's that make up the value for r.

---

To be a bit more clear about what I want.
I think the application is storing data about ticked checkboxes in binary.
So for a group of checkboxes:

- Unchecked (0)
- Checked (1)
- Checked (1)
- Checked (1)
- Unchecked (0)
- Unchecked (0)
- Checked (1)
- Unchecked (0)

it stores the value "r" and I want to see the binary or hex of the value that is stored. So for the value "r" I want to get the hex value "72" or the binary value "0111 0010"

Answer (score 4):

Storing binary data in a text column is not a good idea. You can use the type `bytea`, e.g.:

```
drop table if exists my_table;
create table my_table(id serial primary key, switch bytea);
insert into my_table (switch) values
('\x7272'),
('\x1111'),
('\xffff');
```

You can easily set and get values in hex format, convert them to bit strings, get/set individual bytes/bits, e.g.:

```
select id, 
    switch,
    right(switch::text, -1)::bit(16) as bits, 
    right(switch::text, -1)::bit(16)::int as int,
    get_byte(switch, 0)
from my_table;

 id | switch |       bits       |  int  | get_byte 
----+--------+------------------+-------+----------
  1 | \x7272 | 0111001001110010 | 29298 |      114
  2 | \x1111 | 0001000100010001 |  4369 |       17
  3 | \xffff | 1111111111111111 | 65535 |      255
(3 rows)
```

You can cast a `text` (`varchar`) to `bytea`:

```
select 'r'::bytea;

 bytea 
-------
 \x72
(1 row)
```

Note that in some tools (e.g. PgAdmin III) you should set the parameter to get hex output:

```
set bytea_output to hex;
```

Per the documentation:

> The output format depends on the configuration parameter bytea_output; the default is hex. (Note that the hex format was introduced in PostgreSQL 9.0; earlier versions and some tools don't understand it.)

Read also in the documentation:

- [Binary Data Types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-binary.html)
- [Binary String Functions and Operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-binarystring.html)
- [Bit String Types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-bit.html)
- [Bit String Functions and Operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-bitstring.html)

Answer (score 0):

Using `varchar` for this is a bad idea. For example, you cannot store zero bytes that way.

Anyway, the answer to your question should be a simple type cast:

```
CAST(textcol AS bytea)
```

Comment: this changed the data type but hasn't changed how it is being displayed for me.

Comment: Then try casting the `bytea` to `bit varying`.

Comment: This does not work if `textcol` contains backslashes.

Comment: @cstork Does doubling the backslashes help?

Comment: Yes, exactly. ;-)  I just had this problem and maybe you know a way to solve this without this ugly `replace(textcol, '\', '\\')` detour? It seems to me that somehow it has to be possible to access the binary representation of `textcol` without first transforming the whole string just to receive what you started with but with type `bytea`. Any idea?